# Selecting data from 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My query is as below....

```
Select UserMaster.FName,
       ForumMaster.Topic,
       ForumMaster.TopicID,
       ForumMaster.DateCreated,
       (
            select CommentMaster.TopicID, COUNT(CommentMaster.CommentID)as [count] 
            from CommentMaster,ForumMaster 
            where ForumMaster.TopicID=CommentMaster.TopicID 
            group by CommentMaster.TopicID
       ) 
from UserMaster inner join ForumMaster 
on UserMaster.UserID=ForumMaster.UserID
```

My Tables as follows...

UserMaster(UserID,FName,LName)

CommentMaster(CommentID,TopicID)

ForumMaster(TopicID,UserID,Topic,DateCreated)

and  i m getting below error.....

> "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS"

Expected Results...

Fname | Topic | TopicID | DateCreated | count

---

abc    |    Java | 001 | 2-1-2013 | 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your query as below

```
Select UserMaster.FName,
       ForumMaster.Topic,
       ForumMaster.TopicID,
       ForumMaster.DateCreated,
       c.[count]
from ForumMaster 
inner join (select CommentMaster.TopicID, COUNT(CommentMaster.CommentID) as [count] group by CommentMaster.TopicID) as c
    on ForumMaster.TopicID=c.TopicID 
inner join UserMaster 
    on UserMaster.UserID=ForumMaster.UserID
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your query, fixed up with proper join syntax and table aliases:

```
Select um.FName, fm.Topic, fm.TopicID, fm.DateCreated,
       (select cm.TopicID, COUNT(cm.CommentID)as [count]
        from CommentMaster cm join
             ForumMaster fm
             on fm.TopicID = cm.TopicID
        group by cm.TopicID
       )
from UserMaster um inner join
     ForumMaster fm
     on um.UserID = fm.UserID;
```

The subquery in the nested `select` has two return values.  That is a no-no.  What you want is a correlated subquery or an explicit aggregation.  Here is the explicit aggregation:

```
Select um.FName, fm.Topic, fm.TopicID, fm.DateCreated, coalesce(c.[count], 0) as [count]
from UserMaster um inner join
     ForumMaster fm
     on um.UserID = fm.UserID left join
     (select cm.TopicID, COUNT(cm.CommentID)as [count]
      from CommentMaster cm
      group by cm.TopicID
     ) c
     on c.TopidId = fm.TopicId;
```

Note that the table `ForumMaster` is not needed in the subquery.